# Android Webview Autocomplete Text Color

Tags: android, textfield, android-webview

I have a WebView integrated into my application. The problem I am facing is with the autocomplete that pops up when the WebView recognizes that there was a value previously entered into the text field. The text in the autocomplete seems to be white in color. I haven't added any functionality to these textfields. The webpage is being displayed as is. Would anyone know why something like this is happening? Is there a way to set the color of the text to black?

In the screenshot attached, the user is trying to enter an email into the text field and the white autocomplete dropdown pops up.

The following code shows how I create the Webview:

**myxml.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id = "@+id/viewFrame"
android:background="@color/myColor">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:id  = "@+id/imageLayout">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/loading_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/loading_ic"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layerType="software" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 mWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
```

[image: White Text in AutoComplete]

**EDIT: Solution**

*After working on this for several hours, I finally figured out what the problem was. I am posting the solution here so that it might be helpful to others who might be facing a similar issue. The problem, as I understand is with how WebView replaces input fields on a webpage. It overlays each input field with a WebTextView (part of WebKit). This WebTextView is a child of Android.Widget.Autocomplete.
Basically, setting a style for autocomplete and DropDownItem seems to be the solution:*

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextViewLight</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.DropDownItemLight</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.AutoCompleteTextViewLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.DropDownItemLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>
```

*Now apply the ActivityTheme to the activity in the manifest as follows:*

```
android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme"
```

*This [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237) was instrumental in helping me resolve the issue.*

Comment: Show code. Else it will be just pointless guessworks.

Comment: I am not sure how code would help here, since I haven't altered the functionality in anyway. But since you point it out, I have included some code to show how I initialize the webView.

Comment: +1 - Great question with screenshots and posted solution.